# Apache Camel timeout synchronous route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I was trwing to construct a synchronous route with timeout using Apache Camel, and I couldn't find anything in the framework with resolve it.
So I decided to build a process with make it for me.

```
public class TimeOutProcessor implements Processor {

private String route;
private Integer timeout;

public TimeOutProcessor(String route, Integer timeout) {
    this.route = route;
    this.timeout = timeout;
}


@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    Future<Exchange> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Exchange>() {

        public Exchange call() {
            // Check for field rating

            ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getFromEndpoint().getCamelContext().createProducerTemplate();
            return producerTemplate.send(route, exchange);
        }
    });
    try {
        exchange.getIn().setBody(future.get(
                timeout,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        throw new TimeoutException("a timeout problem occurred");
    }
    executor.shutdownNow();
}
```

And I call this process this way:

```
.process(new TimeOutProcessor("direct:myRoute",
                Integer.valueOf(this.getContext().resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{timeout}}")))
```

I wanna know if my way is the recomended way to do it, if it is not, what is the best way for build a synchronous route with timeout?

Comment: What is your exact use case? I see no reason to apply a timeout to a direct route in Camel. Why do you need that?

Comment: Because my route needs to communicate with a Database, and this route must to be synchronous, and because a necessity this route need to execute in a specific time.

Comment: There are some Async APIs on ProducerTemplate you can use to send, and get back a `Future` which you can then get with a timeout.

Comment: But, I need a sync route. Have some way to transform an async route in a sync just for use the timeout?

Comment: What https://stackoverflow.com/users/406429/claus-ibsen means is you can use a bean with a `ProducerTemplate` that calls the direct route with an async method like `asyncSend` (see [here](http://camel.apache.org/async) for more). That gives you **immediately** a Java `Future`. On this `Future` you can ask for the result with a timeout (see `get` method with timeout in [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). You have a sync route and you call it with a timeout.

Comment: Can't you just specify a timeout on your database command?

Comment: Thank you Ibsen and burki, it works for me.

And about put the timeout in my database, I did it, but I need to call more than one time other databases, and I need to have a timeout for the route.

Comment: @burki in my case, the ProducerTemplate is just getting stuck out of the sudden and hangs internally. I'd have loved to apply a timeout, because I wasn't aware that this is even possible

Comment: @MarianKlühspies I am sorry, but this question is 5 years old. Links are already broken because Camel had multiple major versions since then. It is impossible to help you based on a short comment. Please ask a new and detailed question for your problem. Thanks

Comment: @burki thanks, I figured it out already. The ProducerTemplate call hang because the called direct route had called an external service that did not respond, and the default timeout seemed to be too high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thanks the people who answer me.

That is my final code:

```
public class TimeOutProcessor implements Processor {

private String route;
private Integer timeout;

public TimeOutProcessor(String route, Integer timeout) {
    this.route = route;
    this.timeout = timeout;
}


@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Future<Exchange> future = null;
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getFromEndpoint().getCamelContext().createProducerTemplate();
    try {

        future = producerTemplate.asyncSend(route, exchange);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(future.get(
                timeout,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        producerTemplate.stop();
        future.cancel(true);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        producerTemplate.stop();
        future.cancel(true);
        throw new TimeoutException("a timeout problem occurred");
    }

}
}
```