# How can i specify timout in apache camel route

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, dsl

I have an apache camel route i want to specify timeout for that route if that route does not get completed in that timeout need to raise timeout exception.
eq:

`<route id="id">
    <from uri="xyz"/>
     //does some calculation call some other routes.
    </route>`

Answer (score 0):

You may use **Camel async API** to implement what you want. Take a look at similar question (and solution) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308074/apache-camel-timeout-synchronous-route).