# How to set CAMEL rest services 's server timeout

Tags: rest, apache-camel, settimeout

I have a question about "How to set CAMEL rest services 's timeout"
Not the httpclient's timeout setting.
Ex:

```
rest("/say")
  .get("/hello").to("direct:hello")

from("direct:hello")
**//start action**
   .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
   .process(new Processor() {      
           public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            ...   
            exchange.getOut().setBody(answer);     
        }
    });
  .some check function
  .toD("http4://xxxxxx")
  .transform().XXX
  .setHeader(xxxx);
**//end action**
```

If someone call the GET../say/hello, the time from start action to end action may be take too long.
this service will cancel the request itself. 
(So I need to set the timeout time ,and than to handle the response's massage).

I don't know how to do it or any keyword/component that I can use.

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks

Comment: You should probably enable some exception handling, see https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html

Comment: Hi ,I set onException(xxxException.class) is work, but I don't know how to set the time and trigger the Exception.

Comment: Did you try going through the Saga EIP. This might be a good use case for that to implement within a route, and that has the timeout option.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do with Saga.  I try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308074/apache-camel-timeout-synchronous-route) in process(), but it will block at 'future get' .  by the way, I use component(servlet) to start route ,it seems no timeout option.